# Beginner Programmer: Java String Manipulation

Tags: java, string

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here? I'm trying to display the position of asterisks but i keep getting 1 in return.

package proj2;
import java.util.Scanner;

```
/**
 * <p> Title: Project 2: String Manipulation </p>
 * <p> Description: Ask the user to enter a URL and it will display
 * the protocol, domain name and file name specified. </p>
 * @author Mario Mendoza
 *
 */

public class Project2 {
    /**
     * 
     * @param args arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args ) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in );
        String sentence;
        String word1;
        String word2;
        String word3;
        String word4;
        String asterisks1 = "*";
        String asterisks2 = "*";
        String asterisks3 = "*";
        int firstWord;
        int secondWord;
        int thirdWord;
        int fouthWord;
        int wordLength1;
        int wordLength2;
        int wordLength3;
        int wordLength4;
        int positionOfAsterisks1;
        int positionOfAsterisks2;
        int positionOfAsterisks3;
        char firstLetter;
        int total;


        word1 = s.next();
        word2 = s.next();
        word3 = s.next();
        word4 = s.next();


        System.out.println("You typed " + word1 + asterisks1 + word2 + asterisks2 + word3 + asterisks3 + word4);

        sentence = new String(word1 + asterisks1 + word2 + asterisks2 + word3 + asterisks3 + word4);

        wordLength1 = word1.length();
        System.out.println(word1 + " has length " + wordLength1);
        wordLength2 = word2.length();
        System.out.println(word2 + " has length " + wordLength2);
        wordLength3 = word3.length();
        System.out.println(word3 + " has length " + wordLength3);
        wordLength4 = word4.length();
        System.out.println(word4 + " has length " + wordLength4);

        positionOfAsterisks1 = sentence.indexOf(asterisks1);
        positionOfAsterisks2 = sentence.indexOf(asterisks2);
        positionOfAsterisks3 = sentence.indexOf(asterisks3);
        System.out.println("The asterisks were found at position " + positionOfAsterisks1 + ", " + positionOfAsterisks2 + ", and " + positionOfAsterisks3);
    }
}
```

Have your program perform the following tasks:
 Prompt the user to enter a String containing exactly four words, separated only
by asterisks. The input string should not have any spaces. An example of the kind
of input this program will receive is I*love*computer*science. Display the
user’s input (as a confirmation to the user that the program understood the input).
 Store each of the four words separately.
 Display each word with its length. For example:
I has length 1.
love has length 4.
computer has length 8.
science has length 7.
 Display the position of the asterisks in the original string. For example:
The asterisks were found at positions 1, 6, and 15.
 Display the last letter of the first word.
 Display the total aggregate length of the four words.
In addition, be sure to include a JavaDoc comment at the top of the file, that include’s the
program’s title, description, and author’s name.
4 Sample Run
You typed I*love*computer*science.
I has length 1.
love has length 4.
computer has length 8.
science has length 7.
The asterisks were found at positions 1, 6, and 15.
The last letter of the first word is I.
The total aggregate length of the four words is 20 letters.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What happens when you run your program? Give some example input and output and describe how the output differs from what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are always searching in the given string for the same value, which is `*`. It doesn't matter what you name the variable, you are essentially running this line 3 times:

`positionOfAsterisks1 = sentence.indexOf('*');` using 3 different variables, but each time it will always return 1. This is because each time it starts over, hits the first asterisk, and returns true.

What you need to do is make use of the second argument, which is the **position to start from**.

```
positionOfAsterisks1 = sentence.indexOf(asterisks1);
int temp = positionOfAsterisks1 + 1;
positionOfAsterisks2 = sentence.indexOf(asterisks1,temp);
temp = positionOfAsterisks2 + 1;
positionOfAsterisks3 = sentence.indexOf(asterisks1,temp);
```

**What this does**

The first line returns a value of 1. The next line sets `temp` to 2. Now the search starts from the **third** position (since array indices start at 0), and will thus not include the first asterisk. It will then hit the 7th character which is `*` and return 6. Again temp is set to 7, and again the search starts from the 8th character, and goes on till it hits the asterisk again at 15.

**Note**

You do not need to use 3 separate variables to hold the same `*`, it is only a waste of space. I would recommend using the same variable and eliminating the other two!

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args ) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in );
        String sentence;
        String word1;
        String word2;
        String word3;
        String word4;

        word1 = s.next();
        word2 = s.next();
        word3 = s.next();
        word4 = s.next();

        System.out.println("You typed " + word1 + "*" + word2 + "*" + word3 + "*" + word4);

        sentence = new String(word1 + "*" + word2 + "*" + word3 + "*" + word4);

        System.out.println(word1 + " has length " + word1.length());
        System.out.println(word2 + " has length " + word2.length());
        System.out.println(word3 + " has length " + word3.length());
        System.out.println(word4 + " has length " + word4.length());

        System.out.print("The asterisks were found at position ");

        // get the position of * and store the position index
        int i = 0;
        String positionOfAsterisks = "";
        while (i < sentence.length()){
            if (sentence.charAt(i) == '*')
                positionOfAsterisks += i + ", ";
            i++;
        }
        // remove the last comma and empty space then add in full stop
        positionOfAsterisks = positionOfAsterisks.substring(0, positionOfAsterisks.length()-2);
        positionOfAsterisks += "." ;
        System.out.print(positionOfAsterisks);
    }
```

Instead of using indexOf, I use a loop to iterate through your 'sentence'. Also, I removed the declaration of useless variables.

IndexOf will return just the index it found from the first index (if it's not stated in the 2nd arg of the method). And IndexOf method return the first position as 1 instead of 0.